# Can LinkedIn Authorization work on Android if LinkedIn app is not installed?

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate **Log In With LinkedIn** on my android app. While looking through the developer documentation, I came across this : "*The Mobile SDK for Android requires the official LinkedIn Android application is also installed to support the SDK's capabilities*" ([source](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk))

Does it mean, the user needs to have LinkedIn app installed, to authenticate him/herself? The SDK can't use a webview, if the app is not installed? (like it happens for Twitter/Facebook)

Any thoughts on this will be appreciated

Comment: simply take the sample, import to your workspace, connect the device and run it. see what happens for yourself

Answer (score 7):

As the documentation you quoted states, the native LinkedIn application is presently required in order for the LinkedIn Mobile SDK to successfully authenticate.

Web-based authentication is on the roadmap, but in the meantime, you require the app to be installed.

The SDK will facilitate prompting the users to install the LinkedIn application on their mobile device if it detects that it is not installed when it is needed.  Additional details can be found here:  https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk-auth#ux

Comment: Seems like it is on the roadmap for a long time. Is there maybe a way to do a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you are integrating LinkedIn Login in your application, you might face a difficulty that user must have to installed LinkedIn App in his/her mobile. As per the documentaion,

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk

[image]